# JUnit + generic abstract class test base: always got nullpointerexception in my test, field initialization is not done in abstract method

Tags: java, generics, junit, superclass

In an Jave EE application, I want to create a base test for in-memory database integration test, to initialize the `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`. Also, the service bean to test is not determined, so I make it generic.

I have:

```java
package xxxxx;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;

/**
 *  T: the service bean class to test
 */
public abstract class H2DBIntTestBase<T> {

    protected EntityManager realEntityManager;
    protected static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    protected T serviceBean;

    public abstract void setServiceBean();

    public abstract String getPUName();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // as we cannot statically get class name in @BeforeClass of super class, we have to do
        // it like this. We don't care repetitive creation, as they are the same one, so we don't
        // guard it with sychronization/double check.
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(getPUName());
        }

        realEntityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

        EntityManager spy = spy(realEntityManager);

        setServiceBean();

        try {
            // inject the real entity manager, instead of using mocks
            Field entityManagerField = serviceBean.getClass().getDeclaredField("entityManager");
            entityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
            entityManagerField.set(serviceBean, spy);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("should not reach here");
        }
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        realEntityManager.close();
    }
}
```

And, in my concrete int test:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceBeanIntTest extends H2DBIntTestBase<MyServiceBean> {
    private Query<String> inputQuery;

    @Override
    public void setServiceBean() {
        super.serviceBean = new SubscriptionHistoryPersistenceServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPUName() {
        return serviceBean.getClass().getName();
    }


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        inputQuery = new Query<>();
        ... // other stubbings
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        try {
            // when
            List<SubscriptionHistory> actual = serviceBean.doSth(inputQuery, Enum.TypeA);
// <----------- here serviceBean is always null, why?
            // then
            // assertions
        } catch (DataLookupException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("should not reach here");
        }
    }
}
```

But, I always have NPE in the test, at first in `@After`, then in my `@Test`.

Why my `serviceBean` is not initialized? Shouldn't `@BeforeClass` and `@Before` of super tests are running **BEFORE** child classes?

Mockito: `org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19`
JUnit: `junit:junit:4.11`

I am not using Spring/Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why my serviceBean is not initialized?

Because you've overridden `setup()` in the subclass.

Either give the subclass (or superclass) `setup()` a different name, or invoke the superclass one from the subclass.

Comment: Ah! Silly me. Method got shaded. Thanks.